# Android 4.0 ICS in Samsung galaxy R

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rom, rom-flashing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I want to install Android 4.0 in samsung galaxy R. However i have installed ClockWork in my phone by following [this link](http://www.geekbuzzer.com/category/android-custom-roms/galaxy-roms/). But i haven't find any ICS ROM for samsung galaxy R phone. I have also remarked that the reference i have found to install ICS is all for Samsung galaxy s2, and i have also downloaded the ROM named ALPHA7.zip of Sam. Galx. S2 . If i will install that rom in my sam. galaxy R phone then will it be cause the problem? If yes then please give me a good reference from which i can install ICS in my sam. galx. R phone and also downloadable link of ICS ROM for sam. galaxy R.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for a Galaxy R custom ROM on xda-developers section of your device. ([Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1456))

**Do not flash the Galaxy S II ROMs on your Galaxy R, or you may end up with a unusable device.**

From a quick glance I had on your device's section, it seems that it doesn't have a ICS/CM9 port yet, but that may change.

Currently only CM7 is being ported. Though since your device is lined up for Official ICS update, my advice would be to wait for it.
See more here - [xda-developers Galaxy R Guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1525109)

Comment: Thanks sameer sharma. But why custom rom is removed from every multiupload.com link? From where can i actually download that ROM?

Comment: Which ROM are you trying to download? Most custom ROM developers now uses Google Code to host their ROMs, so you should have a direct link to download.

Comment: I have gone through this site http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1449318, there is a link beside "Download Link :". but when i click on that link i cant find anything except "GT-I9103-Infected.zip" label. Can u pls give me the link of google code link for download?

Comment: @AnandSoni i don't know if it made the news where you are, but the [MegaUpload case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megaupload#Legal_case) was headline news over here a few months ago. Due to that a lot of anonymous file-hosting services like multiupload.com have stopped sharing anonymous files, like the ROMs you're looking for. This is the site owners' attempts to save themselves from court cases, fines and prison. Unfortunately you'll have to wait while the ROM developers find new places that are happy to host their files.

Comment: @AnandSoni Please download from this post, and be sure to read all the tutorials. [xda-developers Galaxy R infected ROM download link post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=22386668&postcount=204)

Comment: @Sameer Sharma & GAThrwn. Thanks for sharing this link. Thanks a lot!!!!